# Not able to get state of component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component with a checkbox and text field when the user clicks the checkbox I am showing the text field which is hidden by default. To achieve this functionality I am using state of this component, as user checks the checkbox I am calling onChangeHandler and setting the state to showAccountNumberField text field and when user unchecks the checkbox hiding the text field. But when I am trying to test this component by doing

`wrapper.setSatate({showAccountNumberField: true})`

I am getting error that state can only be accessed on class component. I am using React 16 and Jest for unit testing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using enzyme? I ask because jest doesn't natively handle react components.

Comment: Yes, I am using enzyme.

Comment: Is the component you are testing class-based or function-based? It would be helpful if you posted the code for the component that you are testing.

Comment: Yes, its a class component but the checkbox and text field are separate function based components inside that class and are called in the render method. I am sorry due to corporate policy I am unable to upload the code here.

Comment: Okay, well, make sure that the wrapper you are calling setState on is the class component. The functional components should just be tested to ensure they are firing their callbacks properly, since they have no state of their own.

Comment: I know that's the problem my wrapper is a class, only thing here is the TextField component is rendered in screen only if the state.showAccountNumber is true and initially it is set to false. So I am not sure how do I make that state property to true and then check if the TextField is rendering on the screen.